# Summary of all the results of all participants after 2015 in ImageNet (ILSVRC) challenge. Does such resource exist?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I have been reading about the ImageNet Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge (ILSVRC). And while I can find the paper by Russakovsky et al. from 2014(updated in 2015), which contains all the information I would want(list of participants, references to their papers, score achieved in each challenge subtask). But it has not been updated since!

I cannot believe that there is no single resource summarizing what has happened in the challenge between 2015 and 2021. Or at least something more recent than 2015. Is there really nothing like that?